In mathematics, does "determine" mean the same as "generate"?
"Any three points А, В, С of a plane a, which do not lie in the same straight line, completely determine that plane"
Here, would "completely determine" be the same as "generate" or "extend"?

Determine and generate are English terms, not mathematical terms. In this case, we are saying that all we need are three non-collinear points to say what the complete set of points in a plane are. Compare that to the statement that two unique points completely determine a line.

No, I think "generate" needs more structure to make sense.

"generate" requires a process by which the given terms produce more terms.  Determine is different.  A person is determined by a bunch of data (official ids, birthdate, fingerprints, whatever).  That person is not generated by that data.

Sometimes (often?) the meaning of "determine" is logical in nature, as opposed to mathematical, but one will still need some context in order to suss out that meaning.
Such is the case here: to say that the points $A,B,C$ determine the plane $a$ means, in this context, that $a$ is the only plane that contains $A,B,C$. To put it another way $a$ is the unique plane that contains $A,B,C$.
I would say that "generate" has no meaning in this context. "Extend" could perhaps be given a meaning, but one would need to specify that meaning, and your short post does not give enough information to do so.

You're right. By "extend" I mean that, for example, you can start from a line segment and "stretch" it like a piece of gum in two directions until it becomes a straight line. Similarly, by "three non-collinear points extend a plane" I mean that you can generate a piece of plane between those 3 points and then stretch it like a piece of gum in all possible directions to then create a plane

@Max I think you can, in some sense, "extend" two points to make a line and "extend" three points to make a plane, but this is not something the points do; it is something you do to the points. On the other hand, the points determine a line or a  plane regardless of whether you do anything about it. So "extend" and "determine" are not synonyms.
